# Rendering with redux and react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Flow:

1. Fetch some posts
2. Store them in the store
3. Display them on the page
4. Navigate to another page
5. Navigate back

According to those 5 steps, you'll already have a list of posts stored in the redux store.

My question is if react will re-render the list when the request will be finished and component will receive the same list of posts as props?

Comment: I just did a last edit to my answer. I hope I helped you understand react and redux a bit more.

Comment: Has any of available answers answered your question? :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically yes. But you don't want to call API from your component. A recommended practice is using [redux-sagas](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga) or some kind of middleware that will handle API calls for you like:

`component -> call fetch -> receive data -> dispatch action creator -> update store -> receive same data from props`

but more like:

`component -> dispatch action creator -> call fetch from API middleware -> receive data -> dispatch action creator -> update store -> receive data from props`

If you are worried about unnecessary rerenders when you change routes and go back you can prevent your component from telling your API middleware to `call fetch`. That way you can get data from store and you will not send another request to API.

This one is by far the easiest [API middleware](https://github.com/agraboso/redux-api-middleware) that can help you started with react and redux

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that earlier, but i'm using the `react-redux` library. So i need to understand, if HOC provided by connect function compares the prev. state to the new one?

Comment: Also, i'm using `redux-thunk` middleware and action creators to dispatch an action (promise) for calling API.

Comment: `react-redux` does shallow comparison

Comment: but leaving the page means unmounting the component so when you go back you are mounting the component again you can't prevent this from happening. that is expected behavior.

Comment: Does shallow comparison mean that there is a chance, that my data wound be updated in case of change in the nested properties on an object?

Comment: And about unmounting - I’m cool with it, but request takes some time, so you’ll see for a second (or longer) some old data after component has been mounted.

Comment: Indeed there is. You should nest data too much when passing them in props. Otherwise, you will have to overwrite `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle. However, you can use immtuable js https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/ with redux. This will make components rerender even you change something in a nested structure.

Comment: `And about unmounting` you want to display spinner while the data is being fetched from API. Just call something like `setState isLoading true` when you start and `setState isLoading false` when you end.

Comment: Oh ok. Also, i watched Dan's Abramov redux screencast and he's showing old todos if they existng in the state. That is how i'm doing. There is one more moment: react is goin to see the change in the posts list and, let's say, append a new one? or re-render the whole list?

Comment: If you use immutablejs correctly (not using toJS) then only one item will be rerendered. If you are using a plain old objects and if you don't write your own shouldComponentUpdate lifecycle then every item on the todo list will re-render.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using react-router, than the list will re-render, because react-route normally unmounts/mounts a component when navigating between routes. 
Having the items in state only means you don't have to fetch them again (if that's desired) and the list can render the items immediately. Only if you reduce a new state will the list be rerendered.